# Why can't I modify my model's virtual attribute in my controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following virtual attribute defined in my model.

```
var ObjectSchema = new Schema({
short_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
})

ObjectSchema.virtual('voted').get(function () {
    return false;
})
```

I try to change it in my controller, yet it still remains unchanged, why is this?

```
Object.find({ short_id: req.params.shortId }).exec(function(err, objects) {
        objects[0].voted = true;
        res.jsonp(objects[0]);
});
```

The JSON still says `object.voted = false`

Answer (score 1):

When you want to freely manipulate the results of a Mongoose query, you can use a [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) query which generates plain JavaScript objects instead of model instances:

```
Object.find({short_id: req.params.shortId}).lean().exec(function(err, objects) {
    objects[0].voted = true;
    res.jsonp(objects[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert all your Mongoose objects to plain JS objects with [.toObject()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) before doing so:

```
Object.findOne({ short_id: req.params.shortId }).exec(function(err, doc) {
  object = doc.toObject();
  object.voted = true;
  res.jsonp(object);
});
```

Or, if you don't need setters, getters, [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) or any other of Mongoose magic to be applied to your  documents, you may use [lean queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) (as [JohnnyHK](/questions/21520080/why-cant-i-modify-my-models-virtual-attribute-in-my-controller#21529224) suggested):

```
Object.findOne({ short_id: req.params.shortId }).lean().exec(function(err, object) {
  object.voted = true;
  res.jsonp(object);
});
```

In this case you'll see all your documents exactly like they are stored in MongoDB. So, there will be no `voted` field despite your virtaul. There will be no `.save()` method either.